# ¿Cómo limito el numero de dígitos que pueden ser recogidos a través de un prompt en JavaScript para que si pasa el limite salga una alert?

Tags: javascript

Esta es mi duda. Quiero recoger una variable por promt, esta variable son DNIs por lo que necesito que en caso de que alguien introduzca mas de 8 digitos salte alert que diga algo asi como alert (`Tu DNI no es correcto. Vuelva a intentarlo`)
Esto es lo que tengo. Se que esta mal pero es que soy muy novato, novato de que llevo días usando javascript y esto me vuelve loco.

```
dni = prompt("¿Cual es tu DNI? Escriba su DNI completo. Letra incluida:")

if (this.value.length > 8) {
   this.value = this.value.slice(0,8); 
} else {
   alert (`Tu DNI no es correcto. Vuelva a intentarlo`)
}
```

Comment: porque hablas de 8 y comparas con 12? y lo que debes hacer es comparar el dni... no "this". `if(dni.length > 8) { alert("Tu DNI no es correcto. Vuelva a intentarlo") }`

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo probé en mi código y funciona perfectamente, eso mismo es lo que buscaba. Gracias.

Comment: Incluye la respuesta en la parte inferior, luego márcala como aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es comparar el dni... no `this`.

```
if(dni.length > 8) { 
    alert("Tu DNI no es correcto. Vuelva a intentarlo") 
}
```